# Claims-based security in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wif, claims-based-identity

We are implementing a claims-based approach to security for our enterprise applications.  I've been looking at the built-in support (with System.IdentityModel) as well as Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) but it doesn't look like either support Silverlight applications.  I realize that SL4 doesn't support IPrincipal et al, but that shouldn't mean we can't still do claims-based auth.

Am I missing samples or documentation showing how to do so in SL4 or am I left to a home-grown solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently discovered that the latest version of the WIF Training Kit contains a sample application showing how to integrate WIF into a Silverlight client.  It includes a version of the WIF IdentityModel code compiled against the Silverlight runtime.  While not an ideal or even long-term solution, it gets me going.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this by Dominic:
http://www.leastprivilege.com/UsingSilverlightToAccessWIFSecuredWCFServices.aspx

or this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Geneva/thread/fe890df3-8815-4d05-b293-d3c87f32e9e0